# PHP 'call stack' errors - unknown cause

Tags: php, session

I have installed wamp server, I have PHP errors showing in an orange table labeled 'call stack'. 
I have the following errors:

```
Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in C:\wamp\www\followup\database\db_conn.php on line 2
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0007  377872  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0127  399168  include( 'C:\wamp\www\followup\admin_header.php' )  ..\index.php:15
3   0.0129  402792  include( 'C:\wamp\www\followup\database\db_conn.php' )  ..\admin_header.php:2
4   0.0129  402824  session_start ( )   ..\db_conn.php:2
```

Please help me to remove this errors in my code.

Answer (score 2):

you use `session_start ( )` in more than one place. you need to start it only 1 place. remove it from db_conn.php and only start at the very top of the header file.

Answer (score 0):

The orange table is the xdebug's error show. xdebug rewrite the error show method, and use the  orange table to show the PHP Error.

The error message shows that you have used "session_start()" function to start a session. Please make sure in a page, you just call "session_start()" only once.

Answer (score 0):

Change your calls to `session_start` to:

```
isset($_SESSION) || session_start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have started the session twice in your code. Just remove one of them or, if you want an extra level of security regarding this kind of error, just check if the session is already started:

```
isset($_SESSION) ? session_start() : NULL ;
```

Hope it helps.